# Wrap malloc but only for some of input files (object and lib)

Tags: c, unix, memory-management, linker, malloc

I need to wrap call to malloc, to serve  memory from my own pool.
But only for my own object files, and some of external libraries.
Other libraries should have access to real malloc.
I use static linking and only link to static libraries (.a archives).

I use --wrap=malloc option to "intercept" call to malloc, but it makes all code from all input files use this malloc (__wrap_malloc).

Ideal solution would be if I could use --wrap linker option but only apply it to some of input files. But other solutions are welcome too.

I can provide dummy example code (which is not that small) if needed to illustrate the problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you're compiling these external libraries yourself, you could just inject a `-Dmalloc=__wrap_malloc` flag...

Comment: I don't, but I could. Thank you. If I'm left with no other option I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try linking in two steps.

First stage: `ld -r -o libwrapped.a --wrap=malloc myobj1.o myobj2.o -lsomelib`

Second stage: `ld -o final -lwrapped -lsomeotherlib`

The `-r` option makes the first file (`wrapped`) relocatable, often called partial linking. Basically you make a library of all the objects you want wrapped, then link that with the ones you don't want wrapped into the final object.

Comment: I'll try that. You'll now if it worked. Thank you. By the way, .a at the end should be excluded, just -lsomelib is required :)

Comment: I'm haveing some problems, I probably made some stupid mistake. I'm having undefined reference error. But I'll fix it on my own.

Comment: I lost few hours, because I didn't notice that -lsomelib isn't the last option passed to linker. And at the end, it does not work. even with new library and -r option, linker does resolve malloc to __wrap_malloc. So final executable always calls real malloc.

Comment: OK, this, seems to actually work. Problem that I had was usage of operator new in C++. What I used --wrap=malloc for both of them it did work, because at this stage linker could resolve code to underlying malloc, but when I separated it linker didn't even know that new will actually call malloc. To overcome the problem, I needed to redefine operator new too.

Comment: @Marko Huh, never would have occurred to me. I try to stick to C as much as possible. Glad this worked out!

Comment: Yea, simplicity is what makes C beautiful. But I had no choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the malloc for only some modules, or even part of modules, I would suggest to use a simple `#define`. This allows to restrict the use of the new malloc to some parts of the same module:

```
...
#define malloc(x)  MyMalloc(x)
...    //From here on will be used the new malloc MyMalloc
#undef malloc
...    //From here on will be used the standard malloc
```

Comment: Doesn't let you restrict memory access to third party libraries, unless you compile them, which may not always be an option. Works for most things, though.

Comment: @mtijanic Yes you're right, but here the request seems to be related to the use of a different allocator for just some modules, and this solution permit also to limit the use to a part of a module. In a more general way if you put it in an header it can just be included at beginning of module (as the last include of course).

Comment: Unfortunately I just realized that I can't use this, because some of libraries are written in C, and some in C++.