# Wrap calls to malloc for third party library libA.a, but not for libB.a

Tags: c++, c, unix, linker

Let's suppose you have object file main.o and two external third party static libraries libA.a and libB.b. And you want to link them together. But you want to wrap calls to malloc from libA.a (replace malloc with your own), but not for libB.a.

How would you do this?

It's interesting problem, but is it solvable?

(to make it more interesting, suppose that it's mix of c and c++ code :) )

**Edit 1:**

To make thing more clear. I'll show you how it can be done for both of libraries:

```
gcc -static -Wl,--wrap=malloc -o main.out main.o mem.o -lA -lB
```

Here mem.o file contains code for function __wrap_malloc. But this will cause both libraries to use custom malloc.
The question is, how to make it work only for one of them?

Comment: Since the libraries are compiled separately I guess it wont be any issues.

Comment: What if libA stores calls a function through a function pointer, that points to a function in libB, and that function calls `malloc`?

Comment: Since `libA` and `libB` are already compiled, they contain direct calls to `CRT`'s memory routines. You cannot override this. You would need to recompile `libA` and use overload/`#define`/delegate.

Comment: You don't compile libraries your self. These are two third party libraries do do not depend on each other. Just main.o depends on them.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek If I won't to wrap calls to malloc for both of them, that would be easy. Without recompiling. I'll edit post.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I have edited the post. I could compile libraries on my own since they are all open source. But that would require a lot of work on build system. Anyway, since it's possible to make it work for both, I think it's interesting to see if it's possible to do for only one of them.

Comment: One question: did you already try to wrap **both** of them? Did it work?

Comment: yes, it really works. You should try your self, but it really work for me. (If I'm not crazy :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good answer came to my other question, that was more specific.

[Wrap malloc but only for some of input files (object and lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31699419/wrap-malloc-but-only-for-some-of-input-files-object-and-lib/31700031#31700031)